# Emacs ESS evaluating slower than normal R

Tags: r, emacs, ess

Is ESS' R-mode also slower for you than just plain R? Mostly the text gets sent really slowly to the other buffer.

Is this normal or is there something wrong with my setup?

As suggested:

```
sessionInfo()

R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22)
Platform: i386-pc-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_2.15.1 tools_2.15.1
```

My custom `.el` file for `R`: http://pastebin.com/WrUxBAyG

Hopefully someone has a clue what might be off.

EDIT: I actually tried disabling all those R packages, and they don't seem to be the problem.

Comment: (10 years later!) I had exactly the same problem ("Everytime I sent a piece of code to the buffer, it blinks at every sentence sent. Is that more information?"). After closing emacs and restarting it works without delay.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
(setq ess-eval-visibly-p nil)
```

Solves the issue of slow blocks of code as mentioned [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/ess-help/2011-March/006734.html)

Comment: I agree that you should accept your own answer in this case, although I hear there are sometimes time limits on when you can do so.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you're doing.  If you're doing a long running command with `C-c C-c` or something it can appear sow.

Sometimes the text wont be written to the `R` buffer until after the process is done.

For simple commands it shouldn't be noticeably slower though.  Googling will show you a bunch of other folks dealing with similar issues.  But without more information we can't tell you much else!

-- edited so the accept can be changed.

Comment: Everytime I sent a piece of code to the buffer, it blinks at every sentence sent. Is that more information? And now that you remind me, the plot window does show up before text had been sent to the buffer.

Comment: I don't think I can debug since my knowledge of ESS is very shallow.  However, posting your `sessionInfo()` and your `.emacs` file may help others out.  If you can create a snippet of code that will recreate the delay you're seeing, that often helps too.

Comment: Any code that I sent has the delay. It is really apparent when you try to execute a function, since then it is being slow on all the lines of the code.

Comment: your "google it" did the trick -_-. ESS is echoing the code (for readability or whatever?), this is really slow. Using the code in my answer solves this.

Comment: I'd go ahead and accept your own answer since its correct and mine just pointed the way!  For science ya know.

Comment: As you wish. Though I suppose that I can't accept it until after some days when it's possible to accept one's own answer.